# Laravel - Update de todos os campos de uma tabela grande

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent, orm

Estou com o seguinte problema...

Estou migrando um sistema, e no mesmo eu possuo uma tabela de clientes

Esta tabela possui um campo chamado "**cli_senha**", no qual representa a senha do cliente

Para utilizar a autenticação do Laravel eu tive que criar uma coluna "**password**"

Agora eu preciso replicar todas as senhas da coluna "**cli_senha**" para a coluna "**password**".

Mas eu não posso simplesmente duplicar a coluna **cli_senha** e renomear para **password**

Ou realizar uma SQL simples para dar um update na coluna **password** levando o valor de **cli_senha** pois o campo **cli_senha** não tem nenhuma criptografia.

Então eu sou obrigado a percorrer todos os campos da tabela, realizando o devido Hash.

Porém a tabela possui mais de 40 mil registros, e toda a vez que eu faço a consulta a tela retorna em branco, eu consigo somente selecionar 5 mil registros através do "chunk"

Alguém teria alguma sugestão ou algum método mais eficiente do que fazer várias paginações e atualizar os seus registros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá,

o código que você fará é bem simples.

```
$users = User::wherePassword(null)->take(5000);
foreach($users as $user){
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->cli_senha);
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, é isso mesmo, eu estou atualizando todos os registros pegando de 5000 em 5000, eu também poderia aumentar o tempo de conexão do Mysql (pra nao fechar depois de 30 segundos)

Comment: Pode ser, mas com esse script não faz mal você perder a conexão por timeout. Ele só vai pegar os registros que estejam com password null. Atualizou, um abraço.. Põe ele numa url e vai rodando quando der hahaha.
É no mysql o timeout?
Se for no php usa set_time_limit(0)

Answer (score 1):

podes criar uma migration para renomear a coluna e atualizar as passwords:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('cli_senha', 'password');
});

foreach(User::all() as $user) {
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
    $user->save();
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/schema#renaming-columns

Comment: Miguel, renomear a coluna apenas, não irá resolver o problema dele, pois as senhas estão sem HASH do laravel. :)

Comment: thx. resposta atualizada